# Rails 4 + Heroku: App will not deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I always use the manual GitHub deployment method to deploy my app to Heroku and today when I tried to do it, the deployment fails during its attempt to access my GitHub.

At the "Receive code from GitHub" step, nothing happens and a notification at the top-right of my screen shows:

[image]

I can't think of any changes I've made other than trying out a new add-on, LogDNA, which I've since removed and the problem persisted.

Comment: https://status.heroku.com/ Heroku has been down intermittently today.

Comment: were you ever ale to get this to work?